# Dictionary error passing data to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm doing a project for my college with entity framework where I need to get multiple data from tables without references to each other. The idea would be that in a list basic information appears and when you click the "details" button it shows all the information including those that are not related to this table.

I tried to do this in the controller but sadly, with no success:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


        ProcessArea processArea = db.ProcessArea.Find(id);
        if (processArea == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        var query = from ap in db.ProcessArea
                    join mg in db.GenericGoal on ap.IdProcessArea equals mg.IdGenericGoal
                    select new ProcessAreaModelView()
                    {
                        InitialsLevelMaturity = mg.Initials,
                        NameLevelMaturity = mg.Name,
                        DescriptionLevelMaturity = mg.Description,
                        Initials = ap.Initials,
                        Name = ap.Name,
                        Description = ap.Description
                    };
        query.ToList();


        return View(query);
    }
```

I have a model called "Process Area" and as I had to do join I believe I have to have another model since they are different information so I created the "ProcessAreaModelView"

When I click on "details" an error appears:

> The template item inserted in the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1 [AkaelApp.Models.AreaProcessoModelView]', but this dictionary requires an item of type 'AkaelApp.Models.AreaProcessoModelView'.

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says, your view is strongly typed to `AreaProcessoModelView`, but your code is passing a an IQueryable of `AreaProcessoModelView`

You need to pass the result of your LINQ query execution to the view , not the query. Since your query expression will return a collection, you need to call `First` or `FirstOrDefault` method on the collection to get a single item you need to pass to the view. Your view is strongly typed to a single object, not a collection

Also you are calling `Find` method on `db.ProcessArea` , but not actually using it (except to check whether it exist or not). You can add your where clause to your LINQ query.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }    
     var item = (from ap in db.ProcessArea
                    join mg in db.GenericGoal on ap.IdProcessArea equals mg.IdGenericGoal
                    where ap .Id == id.Value
                    select new AreaProcessoModelView()
                    {
                        InitialsLevelMaturity = mg.Initials,
                        NameLevelMaturity = mg.Name,
                        DescriptionLevelMaturity = mg.Description,
                        Initials = ap.Initials,
                        Name = ap.Name,
                        Description = ap.Description
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

   if(item ==null)
   {
        return HttpNotFound();  // Or a return a view with message "item not found"
   }
   return View(item);
}
```

This should work assuming your Details view is strongly typed to `AreaProcessoModelView` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a single instance of `AreaProcessoModelView` instead of the query.

```
return View(query.Single());
```

Answer (score 0):

The query returns a list - but you want a single object.  You can use `query.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first match (if more than one match is an error that you want to detect, you can use `SingleOrDefault()`). You don't need the `query.ToList()` BTW (you're literally discarding the result).